# C++17, Intel C++ compiler: what is the library needed to use filesystem header in windows 10 platform?

Tags: c++, windows-10, filesystems, icc

I just need to do some filesystem operation using `#include <filesystem>`, however, I get the below link error ... I guess I am missing a library in the xlink command. Below is the error message.

Please let me know your valuable comments.

```
test_accuracy.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wmemcmp referenced in function "public: class std::filesystem::path & __cdecl std::filesystem::path::operator/=(class std::filesystem::path const &)" (??_0path@filesystem@std@@QEAAAEAV012@AEBV012@@Z)
Debug\test_accuracy.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

**Edit**

Below you can see the compile and link commands. (thx)

```
icl -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/sw_dev_tools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/windows/compiler/include"  -I/../boost_1_73_0 -Qstd=c++17   -Qdiag-error-limit:3                -O3 -MD -Fo:DEBUG/obj/test_accuracy.obj -c test_accuracy.cpp


xilink /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /DEBUG:FASTLINK /TLBID:1 ole32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib -LIBPATH:Debug\lib   -out:Debug/test_accuracy.exe DEBUG/obj/test_accuracy.obj
```

Comment: `wmemcmp` is a symbol in the C runtime. Add your compile and link lines to the question.

Comment: just added the compile and link commands. thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised the problem with Intel C++ Community [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Windows-10-ICL-19-1-2-254-Build-20200623-What-is-the-library-to/m-p/1255833#M38278) and it turns out to be a reproducible issue, and they suggested to update my VS 2019 Community Edition. I updated to 16.8.5 and it worked. So may be it is probably the right solution. (at least worked for me.)

Answer (score 0):

The missing symbol is part of the C runtime. Try adding `vruntime.lib` to your link line, or linking with the MSVC linker (link.exe) instead.

Comment: what is the path for vruntime.lib?

Comment: what is the path for vruntime.lib ? I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vruntime.lib'`

Comment: @MikeITExpert If you have visual studio installed on Windows, typically: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\*\bin\Hostx64\x86`. Its usually adjacent to the compiler.

Comment: *adjacent to the MSVC compiler/linker (cl.exe/link.exe)

Comment: tried it (vcruntime.lib) but didn't help until I updated to VS 2019 (to 16.8.5 from 16.6.5) . but thanks a lot for input.

Comment: @MikeITExpert consider upvoting if you found it helpful :)